# oracle execution plan, trying to understand

Tags: sql, oracle, execution

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
  SELECT sightings.sighting_id, spotters.spotter_name,
         sightings.sighting_date
    FROM sightings
         INNER JOIN spotters
                 ON sightings.spotter_id = spotters.spotter_id
   WHERE sightings.spotter_id = 1255;

SELECT plan_table_output
  FROM table(dbms_xplan.display('plan_table',null,'basic'));




id   Operation                         Name
0    select statement        
1      nested loops
2        table access by index rowid   spotters
3          index unique scan           pk_spotter_ID
4        table access full             sightings
```

Im trying to understand whats exactly going on here does this sound right:

1. First the select statement is evaluated and attributes not in the select list are ignored for the output
2. Nested loop then computes the inner join on spotters.spotters_id = sightings.spotter_id
3. Table access by index rowid retrieves the rows with the rowids that were returned by step 3 from the spotters table
4. Index unique scan, scans spotter_id in PK_SPOTTER_ID index and finds rowids associated rows in the spotters table
5. Table access full, then scans through sightings completely untill sighting_id = 1255 is found

Comment: It seems you have put the wrong execution plan

Comment: yes sorry! ive edited it now

Comment: Read execution plan from the bottom up left to right. `Id` column doesn't indicate that the operation is carried out first.  Even though the execution plan is presented to you in the list(tabular) form it's actually is in tree-shaped form. so you read it starting with leaves. 1. `Index unique scan` goes first then 2. `sightings table access full` 3. `spotters` is accessed by index rowid 4. `nested loop` and finally 5. `select` [find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28274/ex_plan.htm#i19260)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what happens, informally, in the right order:

```
-- The index pk_spotter_id is scanned for at most one row that satisfies spotter_id = 1255
3          index unique scan           pk_spotter_ID

-- The spotter_name column is fetched from the table spotters for the previously found row
2        table access by index rowid   spotters

-- A nested loop is run for each (i.e. at most one) of the previously found rows
1      nested loops

-- That nested loop will scan the entire sightings table for rows that match the join
-- predicate sightings.spotter_id = spotters.spotter_id
4        table access full             sightings

-- That'll be it for your select statement
0    select statement
```

In general (there are tons of exceptions), Oracle execution plans can be read

- Bottom-up
- First sibling first

This means that you go down the tree until you find the first leaf operation (e.g. #3), that'll be executed "first", its results are fed to the parent (e.g. #2), all the siblings are then executed top down, all the siblings' results are also fed to the parent, then the parent result is fed to the grand parent (e.g. #1), until you reach the top operation.

This is a very informal explanation of what happens. Do note there will be many exceptions to these rules once statements become more complex.

Answer (score 2):

NOTE:  THIS ANSWER REFERS TO THE ORIGINAL VERSION OF THE QUESTION.

Oracle is reading the two tables in their entirety.

It is hashing each of the tables based on the `join` keys -- "re-ordering" the tables so similar keys appear near each other.

It is doing the join.

It is then doing the calculations for the final `select` and returning the results to the user.

Comment: Only one of the tables is being hashed in advance. The other table is being streamed.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov, the question was first posted with a wrong execution plan that contained hash join.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz Ah, I see, Op edited the question after an answer had been posted... I'll remove my previous comment despite incorrect description of hash join processing.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov, you can see I already commented on the hash join processing.

Answer (score 2):

Steps seem to be basically correct but should be buttom-up.
The projection (choosing the relevant columns) is optimally done as early as possible at the scan phase.
The index operation is SEEK (you are not scanning the whole index)

Comment: @01ldaniels, does it answer your question? Do you need any clarification?